# Transposing Dataframes in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm attempting to Transpose a data frame in a R Shiny App using Tidyr/Dplyr techniques and can't seem to get a result that is desired. For example, I have the below table

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CDrh.png)

I'd like to transpose it to the following data frame.

[Desired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa218.png)

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dates <- c('2022-06-01','2022-06-02','2022-06-03','2022-06-04','2022-06-05')
price <- c(11,18,15,10,15)
Quantity <- c(20,19,14,19,17)
Tax <- c(2,4,4,1,5)

df <- data.frame(dates,price,Quantity, Tax)

df <-  df %>% 
  mutate(dates = str_replace(str_sub(dates, start= -5), "-", "/")) %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from= dates, values_from= c(price, Quantity, Tax))

df
```

Comment: Please include some sample data so we can run the code and test possible solutions. If you run `dput(head(df))` you can paste the code "recipe" into the body of your question so we can play along at home.

Comment: Please explain what "can't seem to get a result that is desired" means. We can't run your code, so we don't know what result you are getting and how it might vary from what you want.

Comment: Hey Jon, I included pictures of the original and desired data frame, due to imitations. I'm unable to embed the actual picture, the link in the original question should show the picture.

Answer (score 3):

This is just `t`ransposing the data. In base R:

```
setNames(data.frame(t(df[-1])), df$dates)

         2022-06-01 2022-06-02 2022-06-03 2022-06-04 2022-06-05
price            11         18         15         10         15
Quantity         20         19         14         19         17
Tax               2          4          4          1          5
```

Using `data.table`:

```
 data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'dates', keep.names = 'rn')

        rn 2022-06-01 2022-06-02 2022-06-03 2022-06-04 2022-06-05
1    price         11         18         15         10         15
2 Quantity         20         19         14         19         17
3      Tax          2          4          4          1          5
```

Answer (score 3):

The other method using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(tibble)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(, cols = -dates) %>%
  pivot_wider(, names_from = dates) %>%
  rename("dates" = 1) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

```
     dates 2022-06-01 2022-06-02 2022-06-03 2022-06-04 2022-06-05
1    price         11         18         15         10         15
2 Quantity         20         19         14         19         17
3      Tax          2          4          4          1          5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rotate_df` from `sjmisc`:

```
library(sjmisc)

df %>% 
  rotate_df(cn = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
         2022-06-01 2022-06-02 2022-06-03 2022-06-04 2022-06-05
price            11         18         15         10         15
Quantity         20         19         14         19         17
Tax               2          4          4          1          5
```